# How to prints the built in functions name used in our program using a specific header file in C?

Tags: c, header-files

I need to find the built-in functions used  in our program from a specific header file.

For example, I have the C file below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("a = %d\n", a);
}
```

If I given the stdio.h header file to any command, it needs to give the output as below:

```
scanf
printf
```

Is there any built-in command to get this?

Or any options available in the gcc or cc command to get this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't a standard command to do this.  It requires parsing the source file and identifying which symbols are declared in the header(s).  Do you need to know about macros and variables?  For example, given a line `fseek(stdin, 0L, SEEK_END)`, do you need just `fseek`, or do you need `stdin` and `SEEK_END` too?  Suppose the code only includes user-defined headers, but those include system headers — do the symbols need to be dug out?  What about `#define A(b, c) c##b` plus invocations such as: `fprintf(A(err,std), "Failed to open file %s\n", filename)`?

Comment: It is somewhat unclear what you are asking, but your options are to take the header filename as input, parse the program source the obtain the function names, and finally either parse `stdio.h` itself searching for a match, or parse the *man page* for `stdio.h` (if installed on your system). Either way you need to determine how to handle the issues in Johathan's comment, and how to handle functions contained in files *indirectly included* in some of the header files.

Comment: Same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37741109/how-to-find-out-which-functions-are-present-in-which-header-file-in-c-source-cod). Looks like some homework assignement.

Comment: What do you need this data for? Maybe there is a better overall way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GCC as compiler, you can run this command:

```
echo "#include <stdio.h>" | gcc -E -
```

This will print many lines from the `stdio.h` header, and from the files that are included by that header, and so on.

Some lines look like `#line …`, they tell you where the following lines come from.

You can analyze these lines, but extracting the functions from them (parsing) is quite complicated. But if you just want a quick, unreliable check, you could search whether these lines contain the word `scanf` or `printf`.

**EDIT**

As suggested in a comment, the `-aux-info` is more useful, but it works only when compiling a file, not when preprocessing. Therefore:

```
cat <<EOF >so.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    fprintf(stdout, "%s%c", argv[i], i < argc - 1 ? ' ' : '\n');
  }
  fflush(stdout);
  return ferror(stdout) == -1;
}
EOF

gcc -c so.c -aux-info so.aux
```

Determining the function calls from your program can be done using `objdump`, as follows:

```
objdump -t so.c
```

The above commands give you the raw data. You still need to parse this data and combine it to only give you the data relevant to your question.

Comment: Yikes! that's neat, but 8193 lines on an openssldemo.c file... That's a biggie.

Comment: This is certainly unnecessary. Use [`-aux-info`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options). You still have to manually parse the output file though.

Comment: This is not I expecting. What I want is in my source code, what are the functions used in the specific header file. The header file may have a n number of functions declaration and also definition. But What I want is only the function names used my source code.