# How to find out which functions are present in which header file in C source code?

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
     printf("Checking\n");
     exit(0);
}
```

Before source code, I have two functions one is printf() that is
present in stdio.h header file. Second one is exit() function that is
present in stdlib.h header file.

Now I want the output for this program is:

> printf() function is present in stdio.h
>
> exit() function is present in stdlib.h

Is there any way to find out this?

Comment: If you mean a magic function that do the job: NO there isn't.

Comment: You simply learn what header files are needed for some of these functions. And if you can't learn [there's always references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c), and as a last resort you turn to your favorite search engine.

Comment: You you want some info by `gc`c you can use [-aux-info](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.2/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html) option to print to file those infos. E.g. `gcc test.c -aux-info=infos.txt -o test`

Comment: There is no magic in header files. You can make your own containing just the prototypes for `printf` and `exit`, include *that*, and your program wil compile as usual.

Comment: Same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37739740/how-to-prints-the-built-in-functions-name-used-in-our-program-using-a-specific-h). Looks like some homework assignement.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Depends. Doing this programmatically is non-trivial, so that doesn't sound too fitting for a homework assignment. On the other hand, if the homework assignment was "match the functions used to their header files", then OP is simply trying to get out of studying. They should be using an IDE or static analyzer in the general case, and a book/reference in this case.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no portable way to do this since the header text *doesn't even need to exist in a file at all!* It's quite acceptable under the standard for the `#include <system header file>` to simply modify the environment without reference to a specific *actual* header file so, in that case, you don't have easy access to the information from a program.

In terms of finding out if the header text *is* available, this could range from a simple text search (likely to have false positives since there may be a comment about `printf` in the `math.h` header file) to a full blown C-aware parser (likely to be complicated).

Alternatively, you could just (manually) reference the actual standard since those details are available there, a la:

```
7.21.4.1 The remove function
    Synopsis
        #include <stdio.h>
        int remove(const char *filename);
```

This little snippet from C11 means that the `remove` function can be found in `stdio.h`.

And, if you *still* want a way to do this within a program, simply gather all that knowledge from the standard into a file or data structure (like an associative array) and write code to look up a given identifier, along the lines of:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
const char *lookFor (const char *ident) {
    // These should have ALL identifiers and their
    //   equivalent headers.

    static const char const *identifier[] = { "remove",  "strcpy",   ... };
    static const char const *header[] =     { "stdio.h", "string.h", ... };

    assert (sizeof(identifier) == sizeof(header));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(header) / sizeof(*header); i++)
        if (strcmp (ident, identifier[i]) == 0)
            return header[i];

    return NULL;
}
```